# how to store data in associative array in php

Tags: php, mysql

here is my mysql table data:
 snapshot is this

> ```
> responsible_party_name   delayedtasks
> BJ Hansen                    40
> Chris Wolstenholme           14
> Bob Strobel                  8
> Tim Faltemier                8
> Carli Lyon                   6
> Mary Lynn Wilmore            6
> ```

I have store data in associative array format: I have to store data like this in key value form  how could do that. Here is my array snapshot:

```
 Array
  (
  [0] => Chris Wolstenholme
  [responsible_party_name] => Chris Wolstenholme
  [1] => 14
  [assigned_todo_count] => 14
)
```

1. i want like : in key value pair

   ```
    ['chris']=>30
    ['ankit']=>20
   ```

here is the snapshot of associative array in php , how could put data in key value pair in php.

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. What you want to achieve ? What is your expected output ?

Comment: i want to store data in key value pair. in associative array .

Comment: That looks to me, exactly the response you'd get by retrieving the data using a bog-standard `mysqli_result::fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);` ... or am I missing something?

Comment: Show how you're retrieving your data with PHP

Comment: Please refer this link it may be usefull

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267707/storing-data-in-associative-array-php